# Task tracker running but no job is submitted to it

Tags: hadoop, emr

I am running a 4 core node EMR cluster. I noticed on the aws console that the number of task trackers have reduced from 4 to 3. I checked on all the individual nodes of the cluster and task trackers are running on all of them. It seems one of the tasktracker is not visible to the jobtracker. What could be causing this? Is there a way to rectify this?

Thanks,

Comment: What do the logs say. Do you see any connection failures between Task tracker and job tracker in the logs?

Comment: Have you configured your `/etc/hosts` file correctly? Can you ping/ssh between the nodes?